# Negative Bias from Voltage Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, high-voltage, bias

Can the voltage regulator from [here, Figure 6](http://bee.mif.pg.gda.pl/ciasteczkowypotwor/Noty%20aplikacyjne/Linear%20Technology/an92f.pdf) be used to supply a negative bias to an APD? Would inverting Vin/GND do the trick or could that damage the IC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The voltage multiplier diodes D1-D5 could be reversed (do **not** invert the power to the chip or it will be destroyed) but then the feedback voltage would yield positive feedback, which would not be good.

That could be fixed with an op-amp (and reversing C8, C9), but you might have to fiddle with compensation to get stability and to minimize the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it. There are probably protection diodes between \$V_{IN}\$ and \$GND\$. If you need a negative voltage, you should use a buck-boost regulator instead of a boost regulator.

Comment: I suspected as much. Regarding an alternative buck-boost regulator, any suggestions? I'm having a hard time selecting an appropriate IC